# catching exceptions due to framework

Tags: c#, .net

I wonder if it is possible to catch exceptions in the following case:

The application can be run with an older .net framework version (2.0 or 3.0) but when the application tries to use a feature of a newer framework version (3.5) (since it may not be installed on the system), an exception is thrown. Is there any way to catch this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think is is possible because the application won't even be launched. So there is nothing you can catch. As of newer frameworks I believe it is built in that users get a more descriptive message and are encouraged to download the newest version. You could however create a setup project. There you can specify the needed .net framework version and the user will be notified if they don't have it.

Comment: "an older .net framework version (2.0 or 3.5)". This implies you are also targetting 4.0. So which versions ARE you targetting? Is it just 2.0 and 3.5, or is it 2.0, 3.5 and 4?

Comment: it is 2.0 and 3.0, i have made a type error

Comment: @MCD: What is the exception? Is there any reason why a standard try..catch won't catch it?

Comment: I get System.MissingMethodException:

Comment: You're not going to get an exception thrown, but it would in theory be possible to dynamically load components of a .NET2 "base" application that rely on NET3.5 only if NET3.5 is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you build .net 3.5 application, you can't launch it on an older .net 2.0 environment.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can programmatically check wheather the folder exists or not, and manage your code up to that, for example if the folder:

> C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5

exists then use functions of this version otherwise do something else like showing a message or throwing an exception

But i would set my clients soem conitions to use the application, some of these would be system requirments like having the .Net version which you used while developing the application.

Comment: But could you do this from your application? At what point? The `Main` won't even be called when you don't have the right version, right?

Comment: @Gerald Versluis Im not sure if the application will start and crash once a function of a newuer version is called or at the begining, but one can check this using a shell script before installing or starting the application.

Comment: The application does start but throws an unhandled exception. So checking the versions is the only way at the start and not letting to continue if the version is older?

Answer (score 0):

You can write an application on .Net 2.0, which will check the version of .Net, and run the main application, if .Net 3.5 is installed.